# find closest two points of multiple array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, find, compare

I have:

> ```
> pathx=[15,12,25,39,7]
> path1=[17,32,71,91]
> path2=[52,63,9,29,49,37]
> path3=[43,40,5]
> ```

In reality the path elements is more highest and also number of paths is more highest!

Need find most clossest number from pathx and one of path1,path2,path3.
In this example most closest is 39 from pathx and 40 from path3.
Result need to be path number and element position (pathx position4 and path3 position2).

> After need to join pathx with path3 and result will be
> pathx=[15,12,25,39,40,5,43,7].
>
> And compare new pathx with remain path1,path2 in same mode ... until finish
> all paths. But this can try to make myself ... no problem!
> and values of paths is in reality [x*x+y*y] ... so pythagora distance to be
> easy to calculate ... finally pathx will contain coordinate array [x,y]
> but how did first will try myself to make this

Thanks in advance!

And thank you for first response that was all paths with all paths, i make a mistake when asking first!

Answer (score 0):

this would do it..
there are ways to do it more efficiently but if these are the amounts of numbers we're talking about it should be good enough..

```
  let path1=[17,32,71,91];
  let path2=[15,12,25,39,7];
  let path3=[52,63,9,29,49,37];
  let path4=[43,40,5];
  let paths=[path1,path2,path3,path4];

  let num1 = 0;
  let num2 = 0;
  let minDiff = Number.MAX_VALUE;
  for(let i = 0; i < paths.length - 1; i++){
    let arr=[];
    for(let j = i+1; j < paths.length; j++){
      arr=[...arr, ...paths[j]];
    }
   
    for(let m =0; m< paths[i].length; m++){
      for(let n = 0; n < arr.length; n++){
        let currDiff = Math.abs(paths[i][m] - arr[n]);
        if(currDiff < minDiff){
          minDiff = currDiff;
          num1 = paths[i][m];
          num2 = arr[n];
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

after this `minDiff` will be 1, `num1` will be 39, an `num2` will be 40 :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to create an array with all the points, with data indicating each point's path index, position index, and position.

Next, sort the array by position, and drop items that are surrounded by points on the same path, as these items will definitely not comprise the optimal pair.

Then for each point in the sorted array, calculate the distance to the nearest point on a different path with a higher position (there's no need to consider lower positions since the corresponding pairings would have already been considered earlier in the outer loop). Because of the filtering after sorting, each item will be compared with at most two other items (possibly one from the same path, and one from a different path).

The solution scales `O(n log n)` with the number of points (from sorting, followed by `O(n)` procedures), which could be useful if there are many points for consideration.

Here's an example implementation in Javascript.

```js
const paths = [
    [17, 32, 71, 91],
    [15, 12, 25, 39, 7],
    [52, 63, 9, 29, 49, 37],
    [43, 40, 5]
]

// Add [path_idx, position_idx, position] triples to an array.
let array = [];
for (let i = 0; i < paths.length; ++i) {
    const path = paths[i];
    for (let j = 0; j < path.length; ++j) {
        array.push({path_idx: i, position_idx: j, position: path[j]});
    }
}

// Sort the array by position values.
array.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.position < b.position)
        return -1;
    else if (a.position > b.position)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
});

// Drop items that are surrounded by points on the same path, as these
// items will definitely not comprise the optimal pair.
array = array.filter(function(item, idx) {
    if (idx === 0 || idx === array.length - 1)
        return true;
    const left = array[idx - 1];
    const right = array[idx + 1];
    return item.path_idx !== left.path_idx || item.path_idx !== right.path_idx;

});

// Find the closest items from different paths.
let min_distance = null;
let closest = null;
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    let item_i = array[i];
    for (let j = i + 1; j < array.length; ++j) {
        let item_j = array[j];
        if (item_i.path_idx === item_j.path_idx)
            continue;
        const distance = item_j.position - item_i.position;
        if (min_distance === null || distance < min_distance) {
            min_distance = distance;
            closest = [item_i, item_j];
        }
        break;
    }
}

// Output (zero-indexed):
//   [
//     { path_idx: 1, position_idx: 3, position: 39 },
//     { path_idx: 3, position_idx: 1, position: 40 }
//   ]
console.log(closest);
```

Answer (score 0):

I modify the code ... and the result is that aspected:

```
      <script>


  let pathx=[15,12,25,39,7];
  let path0=[17,32,71,91];
  let path1=[52,63,9,29,49,37];
  let path2=[43,40,5];
  let paths=[path0,path1,path2];

  let num1 = 0;
  let num2 = 0;
  let num3 = 0;
  let num4 = 0;
  let num5 = 0;
  let minDiff = Number.MAX_VALUE;
  for(let i = 0; i < pathx.length; i++){
    for(let m =0; m< paths.length; m++){
      for(let n = 0; n < paths[m].length; n++){
        let currDiff = Math.abs(paths[m][n] - pathx[i]);
        if(currDiff < minDiff){
          minDiff = currDiff;
          num1 = paths[m][n];
          num2 = pathx[i];
          num3 = i;
          num4 = m;
          num5 = n;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
          console.log("minDiff="+minDiff+" num1="+num1+" num2="+num2);
          console.log("pathx["+num3+"]="+num2+" paths["+num4+"]["+num5+"]="+num1)
</script>
```

And result:

```
minDiff=1 num1=40 num2=39
pathx[3]=39 paths[2][1]=40
```